# highcharts json multiple datetime series

Tags: json, graph, highcharts, series

I am trying to graph 2 series on the same graph and not having much luck. The series data is coming from a mysql php backend (json).

An example of the json output is below;

```
[
    {
        "name": [
            "Outside Temperature"
        ],
        "data": [
            "1362992572,9.708",
            "1362992752,9.948",
            "1362992936,9.995",
            "1362993292,10.19"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "inside",
        "data": [
            "1362992572,30",
            "1362992752,30.5",
            "1362992933,30.7",
            "1362993112,30.8",
            "1362993292,30.4"
        ]
    }
]
```

I have the following in my highcharts code - http://pastebin.com/BxQxhJmZ however this does not even generate a graph.

If anyone can assist it would be greatly appreciated. I'm really stumped on how to do something relatively simple by graphing two sets of data!

Comment: How you are invoking highchart? can you put the code also here from the paste bin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your data is formatted incorrectly. I would expect it to look more like:

"data": [
            [1362992572,9.708],
            [1362992752,9.948],
            [1362992936,9.995],
            [1362993292,10.19]
        ]

or

```
"data": [
        {x:1362992572,y:9.708},
        {x:1362992752,y:9.948},
        {x:1362992936,y:9.995},
        {x:1362993292,y:10.19}
    ]
```

If you can, change it in your php backend. If not, you will have to reformat it in javascipt, splitting the string values into two fields on the comma.

Comment: Excellent, I edited my php to output as per your first suggestion and got my graphs working as I would like. Thank-you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In case when you use datetime xAxis, then you need to multiply your values like (1362992572) by 1000, to achive Javascript timestamp format.